# Trigonometry Related Problem involving Quadratic Equations

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solutions of the equations $$\sin^2x+a\sin x+b=0$$
and $$\cos^2x+c \cos x+d=0$$ then $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=$?      I cannot figure out how to start the sum and proceed with it.

Comment: Do you mean that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy both equations or is $\alpha$ a solution of the former and $\beta$ of the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

$$\begin{align} &\sin^2 \alpha + a\sin \alpha + b = \sin^2 \beta + a\sin \beta + b = 0 \\&\to \sin^2 \alpha - \sin^2 \beta +a\sin \alpha - a\sin \beta = 0 \\&\to (\sin \alpha - \sin \beta)(\sin \alpha + \sin \beta + a) = 0\end{align}$$

In the same manner :

$(\cos \alpha - \cos \beta)(\cos \alpha + \cos \beta + c) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

$$\implies\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=-\dfrac a1$$

and $$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=-\dfrac c1$$

On division and using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), $$\dfrac ac=\tan\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}2$$ assuming $\cos\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}2\ne0$

Now $\sin2A=\dfrac{2\tan A}{1+\tan^2A}$

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021356/if-sin-alpha-sin-beta-a-and-cos-alpha-cos-beta-b-then  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490652/prove-that-tan-alpha-beta-2ac-a2-c2

Comment: No, the roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, not their sines or cosines.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, The accepted answer doesn't seem to mean so.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the accepted answer clearly shows that alpha and beta are the roots as they have been replaced with x in the solution.

Comment: Right, my bad...