# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are distinct roots of the equation $p \cos(\theta) + q \sin(\theta) = r,$ then show that $\tan ((\alpha+\beta)/2) = q/p.$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried dividing both sides by $\cos$ and then squaring them. Then I converted $\sec^2(x)$ to $\tan^2(x)$ but still no luck even after substituting values.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833153/if-sin-theta-sin-phi-a-and-cos-theta-cos-phi-b-then-sin-thet and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452631/if-sin-theta-sin-phi-a-and-cos-theta-cos-phi-b-then-find-tan-frac

Comment: See [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/928019/409) to the question ["Cosine of the sum of two solutions of trigonometric equation $a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta=c$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/927530/409).

Answer (score 0):

hint...Put $t=\tan\frac 12\theta$ so that $\cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$.

Then consider the sum and product of the roots of the quadratic in $t$

Answer (score 0):

$$p(\cos\beta-\cos\alpha)=q(\sin\alpha-\sin\beta)$$

Now apply [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)